# Phase or Line V/F Control for ACIM

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, three-phase, stm32f4, induction-motor

I am trying to implement V/F control for 3 phase ACIM using STM32F407 MCU. I am using 6 Complementary outputs of its Adv. Timer 1, Center aligned 256-points PWM waveform. The DC Bus voltage is 600 VDC.

One thing that I am confused about is that since I will be connecting the 3 outputs of the 3-phase Full bridge directly to my ACIM so do i need to generate the 3-Phase -Neutral PWM outputs or 3-Line-Line PWM outputs from the MCU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction motors may be internally delta or wye (star) connected, but they are balanced loads and never require a neutral connection to the power source. Variable frequency drives (VFDs) are never required to provide a neutral to the load.

Comment: Ok. so this means that i would be generating 3-phase line-to-line PWM outputs from my MCU to drive the fullwave 3-phase bridge. I wonder how would that be different if I had to generate 3-phase-neutral PWM outputs?